# SOAP vs REST in a non-CRUD and stateless environment

Tags: web-services, rest, soap

Pretend I am building a simple image-processing API. This API is completely stateless and only needs three items in the request, an image, the image format and an authentication token.

Upon receipt of the image, the server merely processes the image and returns a set of results. 
Ex: I see five faces in this image.

Would this still work with a REST based API? Should this be used with a REST based API?

Most of the examples I have seen when comparing REST and SOAP have been purely CRUD based, so I am slightly confused with how they compare in a scenario such as this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and although this question seems quite broad, I have yet to find a good answer explaining this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST is not about CRUD. It is about resources. So you should ask yourself:

### What are my resources?

One answer could be:

> An image processing job is a resource.

### Create a new image processing job

To create a new image processing job, mak a HTTP `POST` to a collection of jobs.

```
POST /jobs/facefinderjobs
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

The body of this `POST` would be the image.

The server would respond:

```
201 Created
Location: /jobs/facefinderjobs/03125EDA-5044-11E4-98C5-26218ABEA664
```

Here `03125EDA-5044-11E4-98C5-26218ABEA664` is the ID of the job *assigned by the server*.

### Retrieve the status of the job

The client now wants to get the status of the job:

```
GET /jobs/facefinderjobs/03125EDA-5044-11E4-98C5-26218ABEA664
```

If the job is not finished, the server could respond:

```
200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "id": "03125EDA-5044-11E4-98C5-26218ABEA664",
  "status": "processing"
}
```

Later, the client asks again:

```
GET /jobs/facefinderjobs/03125EDA-5044-11E4-98C5-26218ABEA664
```

Now the job is finished and the response from the server is:

```
200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "id": "03125EDA-5044-11E4-98C5-26218ABEA664",
  "status": "finished",
  "faces": 5
}
```

The client would parse the JSON and check the `status` field. If it is `finished`, it can get the number of found faces from the `faces` field.

Comment: Now, is it common in REST To immediately return and have the client poll for the status such as this? Rather than just blocking until it is finished?

Comment: That depends on how long the job takes. Always remember that REST is not RPC (Remote Procedure Call). If you take the R in REST seriously (R = Resource), you should try to think in resources. For jobs, the request pattern I described is a natuaral way of modelling.

Comment: Actually, the "RE" stands for "Representational". And yes, generally REST, as you'll almost certainly be going over HTTP should respond to requests as fast as possible, you do not want to be leaving connection opens. If you find that clients polling for updates is a problem there are ways to mitigate this. Cache control is the initial place to start, if clients respect the cache they will not poll again until the time they have been told it will be worthwhile. If you want clients to know ASAP, you might need to look to "push notifications" but that's leaving the 'strcit' REST realm.